# jqGrid Not showing Results

Tags: asp.net, json, jqgrid

jQuery has always been a headache for me. I just can't seem to understand what and how to get the error.

I am trying to bind the data from .asmx to jqGrid. The code is relatively simple. Please see the codes below

**.aspx page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" Runat="Server">
   <table id="jQGridDemo">
    </table>
    <div id="jQGridDemoPager">
    </div>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/Jgrid.App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

**javascript query to bind the data to jqgrid**

```
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    url: 'ForecastWebservice.asmx/GetType',
    datatype: "json",
    postData: "{}",
    colNames: ['TypeID', 'Name'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'TypeID', index: 'aTypeId'},
        { name: 'Name', index: 'aName'}
    ],
    mtype: 'GET',
    gridview: true,
    sortname: 'aTypeId',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    caption: "Forecast"
});
```

**and this is the JSON response I get in the google chrome developer console**

```
{"d":"[{\"aTypeId\":1,\"aName\":\"Replacement - Regular\"},{\"aTypeId\":3,\"aName\":\"Development - Replacement\"},{\"aTypeId\":5,\"aName\":\"Growth\"}]"}
```

The page has the headers but is unable to load the data.
[image: The page on browser]

Please help. I have gone crazy with javascript coding.If possible, please let me know how can I learn it. I have done coding in C#, vb, SQL, php but unable to get a hang of javascript. It behaves so unpridictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can see some important errors:

1. The data from the web service are wrapped in `"d"` property. You have to inform jqGrid about it by usage `jsonReader: { root: "d", repeatitems: false }`.
2. The data returned from the server is wrong formatted. I suppose that the method `GetType` returns `string` instead of `object` and you made serialization to JSON inside of `GetType`. It's wrong! You need returns just the object and the DotNet will make serialization to JSON itself. Currently you convert object to string and DotNet makes **the second time** serialization of JSON string. Because of the second serialization one can see the results as `{"d":"[{\"aTypeId\":1,\"aName\":\"Replacement - Regular\"},...]"}` instead of `{"d":[{"aTypeId":1,"aName":"Replacement - Regular"},...]}`.
3. The format of returned data shows that you don't make server side paging of data. Thus you should add `loadonce: true` option.
4. You use wrong names on column in `colModel`. The correct would be `[{ name: 'aTypeId'}, { name: 'aName'}]` without any `index` properties.

You should include in the question always which version of jqGrid and from which fork you use. I'd recommend you to use the latest version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) - it's the fork, which I develop.

Comment: This helped. I was returning a string datatype by serializing a list using javaserializable class. I changed the return type to void and used console.request. writeline to return json data. Thanks @Oleg

Comment: @ankitsuhail: You are welcome! Next time you can include the code (or a part of the code) of the webmethod `GetType` which you used.

Comment: I can do it on this question. It might help others. Thanks again.